# POST data will not enqueue to PHP Circular Queue

Tags: php, ajax, circular-buffer, circular-queue

I have a Circular Queue I've made using PHP with all of the generic functions you'd see like dequeue, enqueue, peek etc in a file `queue.php`

I am trying to submit form data using AJAX that has **been pre-sanitised** to a file `save.php` with the `queue.php` included in the file.

**queue.php**

```
#prior queue code omitted as it is not relevant to the question
public function enqueue(string $element) { 
      $this->queue[$this->rear] = $element; 
      $this->rear = ($this->rear + 1) % $this->limit; 
  } 
}
```

**save.php**

```
include("queue.php");
$queue = new CircularQueue(5);

if (isset($_POST['data'])){
    try{
         $queue->enqueue($_POST['data']); 
         echo $queue->peek();
         echo print_r($queue);
    } catch (Exception $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It successfully manages to enqueue one POST data but any successive AJAX will reset the array and keep storing it as the first index.

*e.g.
First AJAX data: 20 

[0] ==> 20

Second AJAX data: 285

[0] ==> 285*

I have checked my queue and it runs as intended when enqueueing in separate lines so **the issue is in the `save.php` file**.

Aim: I want any data sent to this `save.php` file using AJAX to be enqueued accordingly.

*e.g.
First AJAX data: 20 

[0] ==> 20

Second AJAX data: 285

[0] ==> 20 [1] ==> 285*

Comment: Because the data is not resident in memory, the data requested by the two Ajax will not be stored in memory. It is recommended to use redis list to implement queue

Comment: @Davis Would there not be an option **without** using Redis then as I'm unfamiliar with it?

Comment: [redis](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-1-getting-started/chapter-1-getting-to-know-redis/1-2-what-redis-data-structures-look-like/1-2-2-lists-in-redis/)
 | 
[redis for php](https://www.programmersought.com/article/25402722288/)

It's simple and important!